# Why is my Smart Contract function not being recognized by web3?

Tags: solidity, web3js, metamask, javascript

I am trying to develop a new Dapp. I have written the smart contracts and they are working well. I now need to use web3 to interact with the smart contracts, for now using ropsten or rinkeby.

I get the error "Uncaught TypeError: myCollection.methods.getNumberObjects.call(...) is not a function"

Here is the relevant code:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/web3@latest/dist/web3.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="collection_abi.js"></script>

    
window.addEventListener('load', function() {

    window.ethereum.enable();

    // Checking if Web3 has been injected by the browser (Mist/MetaMask)
    if (typeof web3 !== 'undefined') {
        // Use MetaMask's provider
        web3js = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
    } else {
        // set the provider you want from Web3.providers - Ropesten
        web3js = new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:3000");
    }

    web3js.eth.defaultAccount = web3js.eth.accounts[0];

    // Now start app:
    startApp()
  })
```

...

```
function startApp() {
    collectionAddress = '0xaff...'
    myCollection = new web3js.eth.Contract(collectionABI, collectionAddress);

    updateCollection();
    }
```

Here is what I loaded on my windows pc:

- yarn lite-server
- yarn node
- yarn node-gyp
- yarn web3
- yarn web3-eth

Here is package.json:

{
"name": "Test",
"version": "1.0.0",
"main": "index.js",
"scripts": {
"dev": "lite-server",
"test": "echo "Error: no test specified" && exit 1"
},
"repository": "https://github.com/prutovitz/Test.git",
"author": "Philip Rutovitz prutovitz@gmail.com",
"license": "MIT",
"dependencies": {
"lite-server": "^2.6.1",
"node": "^16.10.0",
"node-gyp": "^8.2.0",
"web3": "^1.6.0",
"web3-eth": "^1.6.0"
}
}

Where I get the actual error is:

```
// Update Collection data
function updateCollection() {

    myCollection.getNumberObjects (function(errGNO, resGNO) {
```

getNumberObjects is defined as:

```
function getNumberObjects() public view returns(uint) {
     return objects.length;
} // function getNumberObjects()
```

It seems like web3 is not connecting properly although I do not get an error.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see, I don' see anywhere in your code the syntax where you're actually calling the method. You have the instance of the contract which is `myCollection`but you're not calling the function properly. instead of this:

```
 function updateCollection() {

myCollection.getNumberObjects (function(errGNO, resGNO) {
```

you  can try this:

`let collection = myCollection.methods.getNumberObjects().call()`

Maybe look into class components and functional components for react.js.I think it's a better approach than what you have now. Here's a link to make an idea: https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/manipulating-arrays-and-objects-in-state-with-react

Comment: Thanks. I adapted your code as follows: 
  
let collectionCount = myCollection.methods.getNumberObjects().call()
            .then( function(val) {
                numberOfObjects = val;
                console.log("Count:",numberOfObjects);
   …  
                });

  
This works perfectly!